# Debuggin C program using microsoft visual c++ 2008

Tags: c, debugging, visual-c++

How do i apply break point for a c program in microsoft visual c++ editor?
I tired this - 
1)apply break point for a particular line in my code
2)open visual studio command prompt.
3)compiled my program using
 cl program.c
4)program.exe

Is this the right procedure to follow?

Answer (score 2):

For break points to fire, you have to run the program inside the IDE (Visual C++ editor in your case) wherein you set them, usually using F5.

If you run from a command prompt there is no debugger attached to the process so nothing can detect the breakpoint being hit.  You can also attach a debugger to a running process and set breakpoints to fire *post facto*.

Comment: is it possible to do that for a c program in Visual c++ editor?Because START DEBUGGING(F5) is disabled in DEBUG menu?

Comment: Can you use Visual Studio C++ Express instead of the current editor? I am a bit puzzled why you are allowed to set a BP but not debug.